# Máscara de CPF no textBox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
string numero = "";
private void MaskeditCPF(TextBox txt, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //Verifica de a tecla digitada foi algo diferente de números ou BackSpace
    if (e.Key != Key.Back && (e.Key < Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.D9))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Back && numero.Length > 0) //Se digitou BackSpace então retiramos o último número digitado
            numero = numero.Substring(0, numero.Length - 1);
        else
            numero += Convert.ToChar(e.PlatformKeyCode).ToString(); //Concatenamos o número digitado aos já existentes

        //Verificações para realizar o maskedit em C#. Nesse caso o formato são números com 2 casas decimais
        if (numero.Length == 0)
            txt.Text = "";
        else if (numero.Length < 2)
            txt.Text = "0-0" + numero;
        else if (numero.Length == 2)
            txt.Text = "0-" + numero;
        else
            txt.Text = numero.Substring(0, numero.Length - 2) + "-" + numero.Substring(numero.Length - 2, 2);
    }
}

private void cpf_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MaskeditCPF(cpf, e);
}
```

Encontrei ele em um blog e alterei, porém não sei como transformá-lo em máscara de CPF, assim como ele está o textBox fica: `123456789-01` como faço para ficar `123.456.789-01`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você vai ter que usar o String.Format. No seu caso, você só precisa pegar o conteúdo da sua TextBox e alterar o formato:

```
long CPF = Convert.ToInt64(txt.Text);
string CPFFormatado = String.Format(@"{0:\000\.000\.000\-00}", CPF);
txt.Text = CPFFormatado;
```

Answer (score 2):

Fazer pelo lado cliente não seria melhor? Eis abaixo uma sugestão usando javascript com jQuery.

Esses seriam seus includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput-1.1.4.pack.js"/></script>
```

Aqui temos o jquery em si:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
    });
</script>
```

E aqui a chamada no form:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <input name="cpf" type="text" id="cpf"/>
</form>
```

Claro que tudo isso vai exigir uma adaptação à sua realidade programática.

Comment: Eu não sei nada de Windows Fone, mais Jquery funciona nele?

Comment: Ele ta desenvolvendo em windows-phone no c# não é não? Acho que javascript-jquery não se aplicaria nisso.

Comment: Jquery funciona, mas em outro tipo de aplicação, aplicações em JavaScript (que não têm tantos recursos como aplicações C#), eis o problema, o C# para Windows Phone não tem nenhum método para mascara, o código que usei foi criado do zero para servir como mascara. Mas me perdi na hora de colocar os pontos na mascara, pois é um cáculo manutal com os `.Length`

Comment: Perdão, me desculpe, pois não vi que era WPhone.